# Lotus Notes doesn't send customised button

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I created a customised button with some simple actions attached to it in Lotus Notes 6.5. It's just a simple voting button, which I emailed to a group of nearly 200 people. While sending I got a pop up telling me that the button can't be send. After about 10 seconds I got a first reply asking 'where's the button'. Then an avalanche of very clever emails followed, such as: 'no button', 'where's the button', etc. 
Before I spammed everyon I had tried the email on my work mate and the button went through fine! 
Any ideas? I suspect some security policy.... 
I really need to send this mail and get the survey results, so I don't want to fail again. Any suggestions appreciated.
Many Thanks,
Damo

Comment: What was the error message you received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be an issue if some recipients don't have Notes e-mail account.

Answer (score 0):

If your gathering information then assuming you are going to store the data in a Lotus notes database create a form where they can input it directly and just send them a doc link to the database.

Buttons can be weird because if they contain code that is restricted by the ECL of the workstation then notes may automatically hide the button on the basis that it won't let the code run so hide it by default. You may be able to get round this by having the system admins send the button on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a daft question, but did you actually send the email to other Lotus Notes users via your Notes infrastructure? If not, the mail routers will have stripped the mail of any proprietary Notes stuff as it wings out to the internet.

You mention an error message, what was it exactly? AndrewB mentions that your organisation's ECL may be kicking in; alternatively, if you use 3rd party spam / trojan protection, that might have had something to do with it, I don't know.